# Storytelling, used to and would

Tags: grammar

When we tell a story that happened in the past should we use 'used to' and 'would' for actions that happened regularly in that story. For example in the following what differences do the five forms have? And which one seem the most suitable candidate?

> When I was in junior high, I had a classmate who ***used to draw*** scorpions on a paper and showed it off to students to scare them off.
>
> When I was in junior high, I had a classmate who ***drew*** scorpions on a paper and showed it off to students to scare them off.
>
> When I was in junior high, I had a classmate who ***would*** draw scorpions on a paper and showed it off to students to scare them off.
>
> When I was in junior high, I had a classmate who ***used to*** draw scorpions on a paper and ***would*** show it off to students to scare them off.
>
> When I was in junior high, I had a classmate who ***would*** draw scorpions on a paper and ***would*** show it off to students to scare them off.

Comment: Quite frankly the construction that I'd be concerned with first in your examples is "and showed it off ... to scare them off"  The repetion of 'off' is disconcerting, and it might be better to say, "and showed *them* (the drawings or the scorpions- either way it's plural) to students to scare them off."

Comment: What @Jim said. As to what OP is actually asking about, there's nothing wrong with any of *used to draw, drew, would draw* - it's just stylistic choice. But the second verb needs to agree, so it would be *show, showed* for the first two. Possibly *would show* for the third version, but mostly we'd avoid the clumsy repetition of *would*, and just use plain *show* there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When choosing between *used to* and *would*, they often mean the same thing.  When that's the case, my advice is to go with the more direct option.  In other words:

> When I was a child, we would go to the beach.

is better than

> When I was a child, we used to go to the beach.

For one thing, the word "*used*" can trip up the reader, because we use it in different ways:

> We used plastic pails to build sand castles.  We used to go to the beach.

So, in your case, I would use *would*, not *used to*.

As far as differentiating between *would draw* and *drew*, that depends.  If you are referring to a particular event, then say:

> When I was in junior high, I had a classmate who drew scorpions on paper, then showed it to students to scare them off.

But if this was something your friend did regularly, you might say:

> When I was in junior high, I had one classmate who would draw scorpions on paper, and then show it to students to scare them off.

(I don't think you need a second *would*, because the first *would* can apply to both verbs.  Saying:

> When I was in junior high, I had one classmate who would draw scorpions on paper, and then would show it to students to scare them off.

sounds a bit verbose.)

As a side note, you might want to be careful with the word "*off*."  Sure, *scare off* has a slightly different meaning than *scare*, and *show off* has a slightly different meaning than *show*.  But, using two *offs* so close together sounds off, and makes the reader wonder if either was necessary in the first place.  So:

> When I was in junior high, I had a classmate who drew scorpions on a paper and showed it off to students to scare them off.

becomes:

> When I was in junior high, I had a classmate who drew scorpions on paper, then showed it to students to scare them.

(A good way to improve your writing is to remove unnecessary words, then reread your sentences.  If you haven't lost any meaning from the edit, then you should probably leave the words omitted.)

P.S.  Your junior high classmate sounds like one twisted individual.

Comment: @J.R.- One question, if I say: I had a classmate, who drew scorpions on paper *everyday* in the class. What is the difference between this and the 'would' form? Or 'I went to school everyday' vs 'I would go to school everyday'?

Comment: @Noah: No difference in meaning; it's a stylistic choice.  If I said either "_We would eat fruitcake every Christmas_," or  "_We ate fruitcake every Christmas_," people might question my traditions, but not my grammar.  That said, you have a knack for giving examples that have a different problem than the one you're asking about.  The adjective _everyday_ (which means "commonplace, or ordinary"), is correctly spelled as one word (i.e., "carrying out _everyday_ tasks"), but the adverbial phrase _every day_ (meaning "each day") is always spelled as two words (e.g. "it rained _every day_").

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. You deserve more than an up vote. And I think, I need a punch in the face:)

Answer (score 0):

As expressed above, we can use "used to" and "would" to talk about past actions and events which no longer occur. They can be used interchangeably when refering to past action, for example:

- I used to smoke a pack a day in my twenties.
- I would smoke a pack a day in my twenties.

However, when referring to a past state we must use "used to," as in the following examples:

- I used to live in London. (correct)
- I would live in London. (false)